# Trying to create a new node that must have all nodes with their labels and properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

```
MATCH (el)<-[]-(t:ns1__Terminal)-[]->(cn:ns1__ConnectivityNode)
MERGE (e:pp__Element{label:el1})
RETURN e1
```

> "Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof"

Comment: This is the problem. label:el1.  What is el1?

Comment: Welcome! Note that I edited and formatted your question, including embedding your included image. Not sure why you just edited it, removing the `!` and turning the image reference back into a link. I rolled back your edit, as it's important for people to see images you include, without having to click a link. If you intend to delete the image altogether, then you should do that, instead of hiding the image.

Comment: As for the issue: it appears that @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ already identified it and pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you, i use 'stack overflow' for the first time.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ all elements associated with " (cn:ns1__ConnectivityNode) "

Comment: Note that your `MERGE` is attempting to set a property called `label` to some value stored in `el1`. I'm guessing you meant `el` (in your `MATCH`). Assuming that part is a spelling mistake in your question: you can't set a property's value to be the name of a node. You can only store something like a string, number, or array.